# My html file can't connect to my css file?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have been trying to connect my html and css together but I just can't seem to.
this is what my  looks like:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Angels Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Users/angel/Desktop/webdevangela/css/styles.css">
</head>
```

and I am 100% sure that the path is correct and my file with HTML docs and my file with css documents are in the same hierarchy so I should not have an issue I believe.

Comment: can you show your hierarchy as that will help people with answering your question

Comment: I know the head tag is not closed correctly here but that isn't the issue because I fixed it and it still won't let me

Comment: @richardhpa i have two folders, one has a single file called styles.css and the other folder has four html files, I was trying to post a picture but this is my first time using stack overflow. should I copy my path?

Comment: @Angel That path is incorrect. You should replace the href value with the ENITRE link to the .css file ("Https://www" included)

Comment: hi @StarshipladDev I did put the full correct path I just didn't know if I should put it on here, I even copied it straight from the styles.css folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your file structure is like this based on what you said.

```
/webdevangela
  /css
    style.css
  /html
    *.html
```

So your link needs to go out of your html folder by using `../` and then into the css folder.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
```